# Voice recognizer breaks voice synthesizer

Tags: ios, swift3, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I must be overlooking something, but when I try to combine voice synthesis and voice recognition in Swift, I get bad results ("Could not get attribute 'LocalURL': Error Domain=MobileAssetError Code=1 "Unable to copy asset attributes" UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset attributes}") and the final result is that after that I am able to do speech to text, but text to speech is ruined until restart of the app.

```
let identifier = "\(Locale.current.languageCode!)_\(Locale.current.regionCode!)" // e.g. en-US
speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: identifier))!

if audioEngine.isRunning {
    audioEngine.stop() // will also stop playing music.
    recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
    speechButton.isEnabled = false
} else {
    recordSpeech() // here we do steps 1 .. 12
}

// recordSpeech() :

if recognitionTask != nil {  // Step 1
    recognitionTask?.cancel()
    recognitionTask = nil
}

let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()  // Step 2
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
    try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
    try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
} catch {
    print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
}

recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()  // Step 3

guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else {
    fatalError("Audio engine has no input node")
}  // Step 4

guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
    fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
} // Step 5

recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true  // Step 6

recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in  // Step 7

    var isFinal = false  // Step 8

    if result != nil {

        print(result?.bestTranscription.formattedString as Any)

        isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!
        if (isFinal) {
            if (result != nil) {
                self.speechOutput.text = self.speechOutput.text + "\n" + (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)!
            }
        }
    }

    if error != nil || isFinal {  // Step 10
        self.audioEngine.stop()
        inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

        self.recognitionRequest = nil
        self.recognitionTask = nil
        self.speechButton.isEnabled = true

    }
})

let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)  // Step 11
inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, when) in
    self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
}

audioEngine.prepare()  // Step 12

do {
    try audioEngine.start()
} catch {
    print("audioEngine couldn't start because of an error.")
}
```

I used thus tutorial to base my code upon:

http://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/

```swift
func say(_ something : String, lang : String ) {


    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synth.delegate = self


    print(something) // debug code, works fine
    let identifier = "\(Locale.current.languageCode!)-\(Locale.current.regionCode!)"
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: something)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: identifier)

    synth.speak(utterance)
}
```

So if I use the "say" method on it's own it works well, if I combine the two, after doing speech recognition, the synthesizer does not work anymore. Any hints into the direction of the solution? I suppose something is not being gracefully restored to it's prior state, but I can't seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Grrr...

This is the solution, sorry about not looking well enough, costed me a lot of time though.

```swift
func say(_ something : String, lang : String ) {

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        // this is the solution:
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
        // the recognizer uses AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord
        // so we want to set it to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
        // again before we can say something
    } catch {
        print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
    }

    synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    synth.delegate = self


    print(something)
    let identifier = "\(Locale.current.languageCode!)-\(Locale.current.regionCode!)"
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: something)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: identifier)

    synth.speak(utterance)

}
```